# android - How to get simple list from db using Room?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am using Component libraries in my android app. in some case it is needed to use Livedata and observe its data but sometimes I just want to get some ordinary  list not Livedata , How can I do that? query DB in simple way

p.s : I use getValue() but it returns null

Answer (score 2):

Use query like this in **DAO**:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME")
fun getListOfData(): List<Data>?
```

this will provide you **list of data** from your table, just like the select query passed in `@Query` parameter.

---

**Edit:**

When calling from **main thread**, you can use handler to do your job in background like below:

```
//Method from where you want your data from Db.
fun getMyList() {
    Thread {
        (your db object).(your dao).getListOfData()
    }.start()
}
```

**or** you can allow your db to execute on main thread when building your room db like below *(Though i wouldn't recommend this)* :

```
Room.databaseBuilder(
            ...
        )
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
```

Comment: can you show me how to call this method? it needs using a not main thread

Comment: @faezesaghafi please check updated answer, let me know if still any issue.

Comment: using `Handler().post` does NOT automagically run its `Runnable` in the background `Thread`

Comment: Yes, i was not clear about how handler works, i'm now. Thanks for your help @pskink

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write query in your Dao which has return type as List and call from your ViewModel  where you need those data.

Example :

//YourDao

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM YourTable")
List<YourModel> getAllYourTableData();
```

//YourRepo

```
public static List<YourModel> getAllData(){
return getYourModelDao.getAllYourTableData();
}
```

//Your ViewModel

```
public void someFunctionWhereYouNeedNormalData(){
//assign to list
YourRepo.getAllData();
}
```

Assuming you have knowledge about repo pattern in android arch components.

Comment: IllegalStateException:  Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Comment: Under your Singleton class where you initialize YourDatabaseClass,

 `appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, YourDatabaseClass.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries() //Add this line
.build();`

Remember, this will allow Room queries to execute in Main Thread.

Comment: this is exactly what I DO NOT want

Comment: You should specify this in your Q.
Anyways, you can use of simple Thread or AsyncTask to achieve the same.